# How to get row references from a formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have been given a sheet with some formulas in them for example:

`=SUM(D4:D1051)` - can pretend this is in cells(1,1)

With VBA how can I pull out the row start and row end?

Ideally i would have `lRowStart = 4` and `lRowEnd = 1051` but I am not sure of the syntax to use to get this.

Comment: Formula is string so you will probably have to parese this string and get the row start/end.

Comment: Without some assumptions on the nature of the formulas, this is somewhat ill-specified. Do all of the formulas that you are interested in depend on a single contiguous block of cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cells that are referenced in the formula using `.Precedents`

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rowStart As Long
Dim rowEnd As Long

On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no precedents
Set rng = Cells(1, 1).Precedents
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rowStart = rng.Row                    'or rng.Areas(1).Row (see edit)
    rowEnd = rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1 'or rng.Areas(1).Row and rng.Areas(1).Rows.Count
Else
    rowStart = 0
    rowEnd = 0
End If
```

---

**Edit** there are a few cases that are tricky. If the formula contains multiple references, e.g. `=SUM(B1:B2) + SUM(D3:D4)` you will get a union of ranges. The same is true if the cells that are referenced have references to other cells themselves.

In these cases, you can use `.Areas` to get the individual areas the range consists of. I'm not sure how they are ordered exactly but it seems that the "top-level" references are first. Example:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ar As Range

Range("A1").Formula = "=sum(B5:B7) + B1"
Range("B6").Formula = "=B3"

Set rng = Range("A1").Precedents

For Each ar In rng.Areas
    Debug.Print ar.Address
Next ar
```

Output:

```
$B$5:$B$7
$B$1
$B$3
```

However be careful as areas will be combined if the are next to each other.

It also seems that it can't handle references to other sheets very well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
for x = range("a1").Precedents(1).row to range("a1").Precedents(range("a1").Precedents.Count).row
```

If there are no formula in the range :)

or something along these lines.

```
Dim strFormula
Dim lngStartRow As Long
Dim lngEndRow As Long

strFormula = Replace(Replace(Cells(1, 1).Formula, "=SUM(", vbNullString), ")", vbNullString)
lngStartRow = Range(Split(strFormula, ":")(0)).Row
lngEndRow = Range(Split(strFormula, ":")(1)).Row
```

or even extract the range address then use foreach on the range .Rows, just no need for the split to get the range address.

Comment: What if cells in the range D4:D1051 themselves have formulas?