# How to output the Range (or row numbers) of a Formula in a specified cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Done a couple of hours of searching and haven't quite found what I'm looking for. I'm generally searching for things like "extract range value from formula" etc, but it doesn't really give me what I need. I even looked through the "Similar Questions" section as I typed out my title.

I rely entirely on searching for help with how to write snippets of VBA, and so far I've done fine until this point.

What I am trying to do:

OK I will clarify what I'm trying to do per suggestion from Pᴇʜ

1. I have a worksheet with thousands of lines of data (10k - 30k lines)
2. A previous employee has gone through these manually and manually entered Avg, Min, Max, Std Dev rows in between the raw data. The number of rows calculated above was not always consistent (sometimes 60 rows, sometimes 35, etc)
3. I am searching for the bottom or end row by searching for the text "Avg". This works well. Just find the cell with "AVG", then move up 1 cell and that's my end time.
4. What I am unable to do thus far is find the START row (using loops because there are MANY MANY of these. 30, 40, 50 for each worksheet. And probably 60 worksheets. So it would be inefficient to do this manually)
5. The only way this can be done reliably is to use what's available which is a formula - (example, `=AVERAGE(C50:C110)`). I will always choose the AVERAGE formula and it's always one set of ranges, not multiple sets (per example).
6. As I mentioned, I need to extract the start line from this formula and return it so i can use it somehow to specify which cell to copy and paste and do it in a loop over and over for every data set.

Hope this clarifies my situation. I was trying not to get too detailed, but I guess in hindsight that wasn't the greatest idea.

I apologize.

Scott_Craner's Link to arcadeprecint's answer should work. I just need to modify it to work with loops.

Tips?

Comment: Is the formula always a `AVERAGE` formula? If not, what if the formula conains more than one range?

Comment: Please provide the code that you've used in your attempts, as well as any errors you may have received.

Comment: You may be able to use [`Range.Precedents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.precedents).

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018158/how-to-get-row-references-from-a-formula-vba

Answer (score 3):

If cell A1 contains the formula `=AVERAGE(C50:C110)` then

```
Debug.Print Range("A1").Precedents.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

will return `C50:C110`. If there are more precedent cells the addresses are comma separated eg `=AVERAGE(C50:C110)+B5` results in `C50:C110,B5`.

Alternatively you can loop through the precedents areas to get all addresses separately.

```
Dim iArea As Range
For Each iArea In Range("A1").Precedents
    Debug.Print iArea.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Next iArea
```

---

To get the start and end row of a precedent address you can simply do some row calculation:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("YourAvrCell")

Debug.Print rng.Precedents.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

Debug.Print rng.Precedents.Row
Debug.Print rng.Precedents.Rows.Count + r.Precedents.Row - 1
```

Comment: A helpful straight forward approach :-)

Comment: Formula will always be =AVERAGE (xx:xx). One range. May be 30 of these that I need to find. My process currently is to                                                                        1. find data set #1          2. Find the row which contains the =AVERAGE formula                 3. copy and paste the values of the average formula to another sheet (multiple columns)                4. Find the start row of this AVERAGE equation                          5. Copy and paste C (startRow) to the other sheet                      6. Loop the process for all 30 data sets or however many exist

Comment: I am not sure how printing the Column and Row information into the Immediate window helps, but I am now searching how I can use this. I am looking to store as a row value (variable) in a loop or as a cell value in a loop.

Comment: I don't get it, you ask too many questions, you can only ask one in each post. Please edit your original question show a proper example of what you are trying to do. Screenshots might help. Also tell what your overal goal is why you want to achieve that.